# DotNetNuke get URL for image uploaded via the FilePicker

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I have a dnn:FilePicker on my settings control for my module.  I can get the path for the image from FilePicker.FilePath.  That gives me something like:

> /Images/Headers/Default.jpg

How on earth do I go from that, to:

> /[virtual directory]/portals/0/Images/Header/Default.jpg

This doesn't seem like something that should be hard to do, but I cannot come up with the right combination of words in Google to get an answer.

Right now I'm doing something like:

```
imgPhoto.ImageUrl = "http://"+PortalAlias.HTTPAlias+"/portals/0/"+DefaultHeaderImage;
```

Where PortalAlias.HTTPAlias resolves to "localhost/[virtual directory]" and DefaultHeaderImage is a property holding the value saved from FilePicker.FilePath

I've read that using Alias is a bad idea and I'm not at all a fan of using the fully qualified URL instead of the relative URL.

There has got to be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following code to get the relative path of the image I upload using the dnn:FilePicker:

```
using DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem;
...

var image = (FileInfo)FileManager.Instance.GetFile(FilePicker.FileID);
if (image != null)
{
    imgPhoto.ImageUrl = FileManager.Instance.GetUrl(image);
}
```

If you need to full url, I use the following code:

```
string baseUrl = (Request.IsSecureConnection ? "https://" : "http://") + base.PortalAlias.HTTPAlias;
var image = (FileInfo)FileManager.Instance.GetFile(FilePicker.FileID);
if (image != null)
{
    imgPhoto.ImageUrl = baseUrl + FileManager.Instance.GetUrl(image);
}
```

Comment: FileManager.Instance is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img_Name = (FileInfo)FileManager.Instance.GetFile(FilePicker.FileID)
```

"FilePicker" 'll be the ID of your DnnFilePicker